# Emulating a Doppler Test under laboratory enviroments

Tags: wireless

**Background**

I intend to test the Doppler effect of LoRa. To do so, I actually had to drive a vehicle at varying speeds ranging from 40-110 kmph at different places on the country while using a low performance SDR like RTL-SDR to capture RF information.

**Experiment set up**
Insert a node into the car and transmit when approaching, leaving. Capture from RTL-SDR and view the chirps later.

**The problems**
This method is difficult because driving a vehicle at such speeds has many limitations. RTL-SDR is not best at capturing RF data such as a well tested USRP. However, its difficult to power a USRP SDR pheripheral on the road. Hence the choice to use RTL.

**The question**
How can I, without driving a vehicle, emulate Doppler effect in the laboratory? What instruments do I need to do this? I know this is possible because I saw a post on twitter which had the following photo. But it stopped its explanation there. I attach that photo to the end of this question as it might give ideas to the person who might answer.

[image]

Comment: If the instrument on the left is a signal generator it may have a chirped pulse function.

Comment: Doppler causes the carrier frequency to go up or down, depending on the speed of the car (and direction) related to the (fixed) station. If you can vary the frequency of your incoming carrier, you are simulating the Doppler effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on exactly what parameters of the signal the receiver is interested in.

Doppler shift changes the frequency of **all** signals, carrier frequency, data rates, modulation offsets etc, by the same ratio.

Generally, as the carrier frequency is orders of magnitude above the data rate, it suffices to tune the signal generator to a different carrier frequency, and leave the data modulation alone, as the absolute shift at those lower frequencies will be negligible.

If the data rates are very high (for instance Ultra WideBand), or the carrier very low, or the Doppler shift very extreme, then you may need to shift the modulation generator parameters as well.

Some signal generators intended for communications test have Doppler capability built in, usually with fading models as well.

Comment: Thanks. So I think I will have to walk around the campus insearch of a signal generator that can do this.  Im very happy you pointed me in the right direction. Thanks again.